# Fixing arrows details on Feynman diagram

Tags: feynmf, feynmp

[image: ee>mm graph]

I'm trying to make a (simple?) Feynman diagram, but there are some details that are bugging me. In particular, the labels of the lines and the labels of the arrows are of different sizes, and the p'/k' arrows aren't centered (there should be equal space before and after the arrows).

The code I'm using is

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{feynmp}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}
\newcommand{\marrow}[5]{%
    \fmfcmd{style_def marrow#1 
    expr p = drawarrow subpath (1/4, 3/4) of p shifted 6 #2 withpen pencircle scaled 0.4; 
    label.#3 (btex #4 etex, point 0.5 of p shifted 6 #2); 
    enddef;}
    \fmf{marrow#1, tension=0}{#5}}
\unitlength=1mm
\begin{document}
\begin{fmffile}{eemm}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(30,35)
    \fmfpen{thin}
    \fmfleft{i1,o1}
    \fmfright{i2,o2}
    \fmflabel{$e^-$}{i1}
    \fmflabel{$e^+$}{i2}
    \fmflabel{$\mu^-$}{o1}
    \fmflabel{$\mu^+$}{o2}
    \fmf{fermion, label=$p$}{i1,v1}
    \fmf{fermion}{v1,i2}
    \fmf{fermion, label=$k$}{v2,o1}
    \fmf{fermion}{v2,o2}
    \fmf{photon}{v1,v2}
    \marrow{a}{down}{bot}{$p'$}{i2,v1}
    \marrow{b}{right}{rt}{$q$}{v1,v2}
    \marrow{c}{down}{bot}{$k'$}{v2,o2}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With your code, after compilation I get a blank page!

Comment: @AndréC I don't know why... I'm using TeXShop. Do you have the feynmp package installed?

Comment: There is no package called `feynmp` on CTAN! [CTAN Search feynman](https://ctan.org/search?phrase=feynman)

Comment: The package is called feynmf on CTAN. The two LaTeX package only differ by if they worth with MetaPost or MetaFont.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can propose an easy solution with`pst-feyn`:

```
\documentclass[x11names, 12pt, border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node, pst-feyn}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
\psset{linejoin=1, arrowinset=0, labelsep=2.5pt}
\psPhoton[windings=4.5, amplitude=3pt](0,-1)(0,1)
\psArrowLine(0,1)(1.3,1.8)\uput[ur](1.3,1.8){$\mu^+ $}
\psArrowLine(0,1)(-1.3,1.8)\uput[ul](-1.3,1.8){$\mu^-$}
\uput[dl](-0.65,1.4){$k$}
\psArrowLine(0,-1)(1.3,-1.8)\uput[dr](1.3,-1.8){$e^+ $}
\psArrowLine(-1.3,-1.8)(0,-1)\uput[dl](-1.3,-1.8){$e^-$}
\uput[dr](-0.65,-1.4){$p$}
\pnodes(0,-0.5){A1}(0,0.5){A2}(0.32,1.2){B1}(0.96,1.60){B2}(0.32,-1.2){C1}(0.96,-1.60){C2}
\psset{arrows=->}
\ncline[offset=-1.2ex]{A1}{A2}\nbput{$q$}
\ncline[offset=-1.2ex]{B1}{B2}\nbput{$k'$}
\ncline[offset=-1.2ex, arrows=<-]{C1}{C2}\nbput{$p'$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks so much better. The p and the p' are a bit off from one another but I'll try to find a fix. There are so many Feynman diagram packages! Do you know which one Peskin and Schroeder used for their QFT book?

Comment: Noideo for the book, but as it dates back to 1995, there are chances that either it was done with a dedicated software as a postscript image, or with`pstricks`, of which `pst-feyn` is a module. What would you like exactly for *p* and *p'*? I tried to make them as close to the image in your post as possible, playing with some pstricks parameters.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using `tikz-feynman` compiling with [lualatex](/questions/tagged/lualatex).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram [vertical'=a to b] {
i1 [particle=\(\mu^{-}\)] -- [fermion] a -- [fermion,momentum'=\(\scriptstyle k'\)] i2 [particle=\(\mu^{+}\)],
a -- [photon,reversed momentum=\(q\)] b,
f1 [particle=\(\mu^{-}\)] -- [fermion] b -- [fermion, reversed momentum'=\(\scriptstyle p'\)] f2 [particle=\(\mu^{+}\)],
};


\end{document}
```

[image]